# Cant get to BIOS menu pages (Insydeh20 setup utility)

Tags: boot, bios, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive, efi

I have been trying to boot a USB pen with the gparted live, but it seems it is not detected. Most solutions that I found require me to access the BIOS setup where I should change the boot priorities and such, but the problem is that I can't get to the BIOS menu. The F2 tile gets me to "InsydeH20 Setup Utility" but it has only one page of information. The F12 gets me to "Boot Manager" where I can choose what device to boot from (but it only shows one, the HDD Device). How do i access the other setup utility pages, like Main, Boot, etc.?

PS: If there's a better place to post this question, please say where

PS: I have tested the USB stick and plug and they are working properly

PS: The first picture is the bios page I'm looking for, where I would be able to get to boot settings like boot priority

["Bios page I'm looking for (image)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUhBf.jpg)

[Boot Manager (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRVTH.jpg)

[InsydeH20 Setup Utility (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fONE5.jpg)

Basically, my Insydeh20 setup utility is only showing the information page (instead of also showing the Main, Security, Boot and Exit pages)

I'm not certain but I might have deleted some EFI partition.
Right now, I only have one EFI partition (EFI system partition)

Comment: The InsydeH20 seems to be the BIOS of your computer. Maybe there are keys in there that go to a different page.

Comment: In the commands lower section of the page, doesn't show any key to change page or anything like that

Comment: And I'm not certain, but I think I use to be able to change pages. And I think I might have deleted some partition efi partition. So it might be because of that the other pages don't appear. Is this possible and probable?

Comment: I have just edited the "Bios page I'm looking for (image)", now it's the actual page that I want to get to